# How can I apply for loop in django template for creating array of same images?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am in need of code in django template without javascript to display the length of same images based on number of votes. My current code is this:

```
<div id="Results">
    <h1>{{question.question_text}}</h1>
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <div id="votes">
        <img style="border-radius: 2px; border-width: 2px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: darkblue;" src='{{choice.image2.url}}'
        />
        <div style=" float: right; width: 88%;">
            <b>{{choice.choice_text}}</b>
            {{choice.votes}} vote{{choice.votes|pluralize}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <p id="info">Your Vote Has Been Stored!!</p>
    <br>
</div>
```

Help me generate code with algorithm:

1. increment for loop based on choice.votes. //for loop from i=0; i<{{choice.votes}}; i++
2. display of some image in array. // some image

Here's my models.py

from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Is Published')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Question_Image", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="Question_Image2", blank=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.choice_text
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your question? What is exactly that you want? What have you tried? Show your `models.py`.

Comment: I still not got your question. What do you mean by 'display the length of same images'.  What is wrong with your current code? You all ready have a loop over the choices do you want to loop over the votes in each change as well? And what does 'display some image of array' mean? Can you maybe give an example or screenshot or spezify your post?